# Elastic Search get top grouped sums with additional filters (Elasticsearch version5.3)

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

This is my **`Mapping`** :

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 2,
        "number_of_replicas" : 1
    },
    "mappings" :{
        "cpt_logs_mapping" : {
            "properties" : {
                "channel_id" : {"type":"integer","store":"yes","index":"not_analyzed"},
                "playing_date" : {"type":"string","store":"yes","index":"not_analyzed"},
                "country_code" : {"type":"text","store":"yes","index":"analyzed"},
                "playtime_in_sec" : {"type":"integer","store":"yes","index":"not_analyzed"},
                "channel_name" : {"type":"text","store":"yes","index":"analyzed"},
                "device_report_tag" : {"type":"text","store":"yes","index":"analyzed"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to query the index similar to the way I do using the following **`MySQL`** query :

```
SELECT 
  channel_name,
  SUM(`playtime_in_sec`) as playtime_in_sec 
FROM
  channel_play_times_bar_chart
WHERE
country_code = 'country' AND 
device_report_tag = 'device' AND
channel_name = 'channel' 
playing_date BETWEEN 'date_range_start' AND 'date_range_end' 
GROUP BY channel_id
ORDER BY SUM(`playtime_in_sec`) DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

So far my **`QueryDSL`** looks like this

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ch_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "channel_id",
        "size": 30 ,
        "order": {
              "sum_agg": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_agg": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "playtime_in_sec"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**QUESTION 1**
 Although the **`QueryDSL`** I have made does return me the top 30 channel_ids w.r.t playtimes but I am confused how to add other filters too within the search i.e country_code, device_report_tag & playing_date.

**QUESTION 2**
 Another issue is that the result set contains only the **`channel_id`** and playtime fields unlike the **`MySQL`** result set which returns me channel_name and playtime_in_sec columns. This means I want to achieve aggregation using channel_id field but result set should instead return corresponding channel_name name of the group.

**`NOTE`**: Performance over here is a top priority as this is supposed to be running behind a graph generator querying millions or even more docs.

**TEST DATA**

```
hits: [
    {
        _index: "cpt_logs_index",
        _type: "cpt_logs_mapping",
        _id: "",
        _score: 1,
        _source: {
            ChID: 1453,
            playtime_in_sec: 35,
            device_report_tag: "mydev",
            channel_report_tag: "Sony Six",
            country_code: "SE",
            @timestamp: "2017-08-11",
        }
    },
    {
        _index: "cpt_logs_index",
        _type: "cpt_logs_mapping",
        _id: "",
        _score: 1,
        _source: {
            ChID: 145,
            playtime_in_sec: 25,
            device_report_tag: "mydev",
            channel_report_tag: "Star Movies",
            country_code: "US",
            @timestamp: "2017-08-11",
        }
    },
    {
        _index: "cpt_logs_index",
        _type: "cpt_logs_mapping",
        _id: "",
        _score: 1,
        _source: {
            ChID: 12,
            playtime_in_sec: 15,
            device_report_tag: "mydev",
            channel_report_tag: "HBO",
            country_code: "PK",
            @timestamp: "2017-08-12",
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

QUESTION1:

Are you looking to add a filter/query to the example above? If so you can simply add a "query" node to the query document:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query":{
    "bool":{
        "must":[
            {"terms": { "country_code": ["pk","us","se"] } },
            {"range": { "@timestamp": { "gt": "2017-01-01", "lte": "2017-08-11"  } } }
            ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "ch_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ChID",
        "size": 30
      },
      "aggs":{
        "ch_report_tag_agg": {
            "terms":{
                "field" :"channel_report_tag.keyword"
            },
            "aggs":{
                "sum_agg":{
                    "sum":{
                    "field":"playtime_in_sec"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use all normal queries/filters for elastic to pre-filter your search before you start aggregating (Regarding performance, elasticsearch will apply any filters / queries before starting to aggregate, so any filtering you can do here will help a lot)

Question2:

On the top of my head I would suggest one of two solutions (unless I'm not completely misunderstanding the question):

1. Add aggs levels for the fields you want in the output in the order you want to drill down. (you can nest aggs within aggs quite deeply without issues and get the bonus of count on each level)
2. Use the top_hits aggregation on the "lowest" level of aggs, and specify which fields you want in the output using "_source": { "include": [/*fields*/] }

Can you provide a few records of test data?

Also, it is useful to know which version of ElasticSearch you're running as the syntax and behaviour change a lot between major versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added some test data. I am using Elasticsearch version 5.3

Comment: @DanishBinSofwan Updated the example with an additional level of aggs to hold the channel ID.
Note that due to your mapping of country code being "analyzed" you will need to filter it in lower-case. If you want it in your aggs as a term you will have to modify the mapping or add a not_analyzed version of it.